# JSON data via AJAX to DIV

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I'm displaying a list of Events using JSON.  Below is the JSON data:

```
[{
    "event_id": "1636",
    "event_name": "Nitelounge supported by Mo\u00ebt &amp; Chandon",
    "event_start_date": "2013-05-27",
    "event_start_time": "21:00:00",
    "event_end_time": "05:00:00",
    "post_content": "Le Baron de Paris\r\n<div>Location:\u00a0Tokyo Aoyama, Japan<\/div>\r\n<div itemprop=\"address\" itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http:\/\/schema.org\/PostalAddress\">Address:\u00a0\u6771\u4eac\u90fd\u6e2f\u533a\u5357\u9752\u5c713-8-40 \u9752\u5c71\u30bb\u30f3\u30bf\u30fc\u30d3\u30ebB1<\/div>\r\n<div>Access: \u8868\u53c2\u9053\u99c5\u304b\u3089\u5f92\u6b695\u5206\uff0f\u5916\u82d1\u524d\u99c5\u304b\u3089\u5f92\u6b695\u5206<\/div>\r\n<div>URL:\u00a0<a itemprop=\"url\" href=\"http:\/\/www.lebaron.jp\/\" target=\"_blank\">www.lebaron.jp<\/a><\/div>\r\n<div>Phone:\u00a003-3408-3665<\/div>",
    "location_id": "21",
    "location_name": "Le Baron de Paris",
    "location_region": "\u6e2f\u533a",
    "logo": "<img src=\"http:\/\/goodnitetokyo.com\/mobile\/images\/club_logo_lebaron.png\" alt=\"NO IMAGE\" width=\"80\" height=\"60\" \/>"
},
```

I have an HTML page that populates the data within a DIV:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "event_list_json.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, dataType) 
        {
            var $content = $('#content');
            for (var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
                $content.append("<div id='content'> <div id='space'> </div><div id='logo'>" + data[i].logo + "</div> <div id='info'> <div id='right-top' style='text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; vertical-align:top;'><span><h1>[イベント]&nbsp" + data[i].event_name + "</h1></span></div> <div id='right-middle'><span><h2>&nbsp"+ data[i].event_start_date + "&nbsp&#8226;&nbsp"+ data[i].event_start_time + "&nbsp-&nbsp" + data[i].event_end_time + "</h2></span></div> <div id='right-bottom' style='vertical-align:top;'><span><h3>&nbsp" + data[i].location_region + "&nbsp&#8226;&nbsp" + data[i].location_name + "</h3></span></div></div> <div id='button'><a href='#' onclick='btn_click(" + i + ")' ><img src='http://goodnitetokyo.com/mobile/images/panel_selected_open_arrow.png' width='23' height='60' /></div></div><hr style='height:2px; visibility:hidden; margin-bottom:-1px;' />");
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

So, what I want to do is if the user clicks the 'button' then another DIV can load the 'post_content' from the JSON data.

Trying to load into this DIV:

```
<div id='panel_wrapper'> 
<div id='panel_button'><img src='images/panel_selected_close_arrow.png' width='23' height='60' /></div>
<div id='panel_content'>  
<div id='panel_logo'><img src='images/club_logo_default.png' width='80' height='60' />            </div>
<div id='panel_info'> 
    <div id='panel_right-top'>TOP</div>
    <div id='panel_right-middle'>MIDDLE</div>
    <div id='panel_right-bottom'>BOTTOM</div>
    <div id='panel_right-post'>POST</div>
</div>
```

"post_content" from JSON loads to  + data[i].post_content + "

How would I do this correctly? I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks guys for your posts. Still lost here.

Answer (score 0):

`event_list_json.php` should echo out one specific record from your JSON array. Then you make an ajax call to it a from in a `$(button).click` handler, as well as from the `$(document).ready` handler. When you make the ajax call, you will need to specify the index of the record that you want to receive.

Also, a `GET` request would be more appropriate than a `POST` since you are not modifying anything on the server side when you make these requests; you are getting data.

Another thing to consider, is what to do if a new event is inserted into the JSON array between ajax requests. I would use a websocket to send an event to the client, but don't worry about that until you have your current problem solved.

Comment: Seems like the correct path. I've updated my question. Can you take a look, please?

Comment: In `$content.append`, you shouldn't insert a new `div#content` into the `div#content` that contains all of the events. There shouldn't be any ids in the generated code, unless they have a unique string like the event number. Almost all of the ids in the generated code should actually be classes. Ids must be unique across the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a clearer flow for your application.  As it is, the page issues a single jQuery POST request when the document is ready, and upon success of that request adds a `div` for each top-level element in your JSON's data, all with the same `id`.

For a start, separate out the tasks you need the page to perform into multiple functions.  At least, you should have a distinct `renderData` and `getData` functions, that can be called from various places in your code.  *Names are examples.  Whatever naming convention makes sense to you is appropriate.*

Once you have your logic in distinct named functions, instead of as anonymous event handlers, you can attach appropriate code to your button's `click` event to request / display more data.

Read-up on [jQuery's ON method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and don't be afraid to ask clarifiying questions.